# Understanding the proof of the Birch's Theorem

Tags: statistics, algebraic-geometry, optimization

Hi guys I am trying to understand the proof of the Birch's Theorem. I am using the proof provided in this paper : https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/owl.pdf

The theorem is on page 41. I am stuck on after we clear the denominators and we obtain $u+\lambda B=- \gamma v$. I do not see how after this the paper claims they have the result. Thank you for the help!!

( I am just trying to understand a paper that overall is above my league but I hoped this one result might be easy to understand.)

Comment: Is the issue why $A(-\gamma\nu) = A\hat u$?

Comment: yes, and why also when you apply $A(u+\lambda B) =Au$

Comment: Well $B$ is in the kernel of $A$ right?  So $A(\lambda B)=0$.

Comment: O sweet you are right, that makes sense. And for the first part why do we call $A(- \gamma v)= A \hat{u}$

Comment: Sorry I don't see why that is true, but that doesn't mean it's not, I just didn't understand well enough to say.

Comment: Thank you anyhow I appreciate taking a look!!